# in modal multiple image not show properly laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using bootstrap modal to show my all image but only one image show in my laravel 5.3 project i can't figure out how to fix it below this code only first image is show if i use @endforeach in the end of code then only show last image.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
@foreach($prizebond_images as $prizebond_image)
    <div class="col-lg-4">                                
       {!! Html::image('images/'.$prizebond_image->prizebond_image,'a picture',['class'=>'img-thumbnail img-responsive','data-target'=>"#myModal",'data-toggle'=>'modal']) !!}
        <p class="text-success">{{$prizebond_image->prizebond_image_rank}}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach

</div>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" width="auto" height="auto">
                {!! Html::image('images/'.$prizebond_image->prizebond_image,'a picture',['class'=>'img-thumbnail img-responsive']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put modal window code inside the loop too. Also, you need to create unqiue ID for each modal and link, use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) for that. For example:

```
@foreach($prizebond_images as $prizebond_image)
    ....      
    {!! Html::image(.... 'data-target' => "#myModal".$loop->index, 'data-toggle'....
    ....
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{ $loop->index }}" tabindex="-1"....
    ....
@endforeach
```